# private network impersonation attack

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, security

I've set up a 5-node network with 3 validator nodes. I would like to test the integrity of the blockchain by having a non-validator node attempt to validate a new transaction. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: You need to sign a block with the private key from node that is not a validator.

Comment: Ok. Is there a functionality to do this in geth?

Comment: I've never done that, I'd guess it is possible if you modify geth source code.